# groovy import org.xhtmlrenderer.simple.Graphics2DRenderer how I could add this in groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

IM trying to execute this code in groovy 2.4 but  appears that the class not exist

I  dont know how install this in groovy

the header org and org.w3c dont exist

please help me with this

this is the code

```
import java.awt.Dimension
import java.awt.Graphics2D
import java.awt.RenderingHints
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import org.w3c.dom.Document
import org.w3c.tidy.Tidy
import org.xhtmlrenderer.simple.Graphics2DRenderer

def makeThumbnail(address) {
  // Size for the renderer
    def WIDTH = 1280
    def HEIGHT = 800

    // Setup Tidy
    def tidy = new Tidy()
    tidy.with {
        setQuiet(true)
        setXHTML(true)
        setHideComments(true)
        setInputEncoding("UTF-8")
        setOutputEncoding("UTF-8")
        setShowErrors(0)
        setShowWarnings(false)
    }

    def url = new URL(address)
    def doc = tidy.parseDOM(new ByteArrayInputStream(url.text.getBytes("UTF-8")), null)
    def os = new FileOutputStream("/Users/ascotti/${url.getHost()}.png")

    def buf = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)

    def graphics = buf.createGraphics()
    def renderer = new Graphics2DRenderer()

    renderer.with {
        setDocument(doc, address)
        layout(graphics, new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        render(graphics)
        graphics.dispose()
        ImageIO.write(buf, "png", os)
    }
}

makeThumbnail("http://www.128bitstudios.com/")
makeThumbnail("http://en.wikipedia.org/")
makeThumbnail("http://misplaced-packets.net/")
makeThumbnail("http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

How  I could install

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document
import org.w3c.tidy.Tidy
import org.xhtmlrenderer.simple.Graphics2DRenderer
```

I install

```
 grape install "org.w3c" "dom" "2.3.0-jaxb-1.0.6"
  grape install "org.xhtmlrenderer" "core-renderer" "R8pre2"
  grape install "net.sf.jtidy" "jtidy" "r938"
```

but appears the same error in grooyv
in groovy 
please help me

Comment: is it a groovy script? in that case you might want to take a look at Grapes (http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html)

Comment: HI fernando I read this article and I install  grape install "org.w3c" "dom" "2.3.0-jaxb-1.0.6"
  grape install "org.xhtmlrenderer" "core-renderer" "R8pre2"
  grape install "net.sf.jtidy" "jtidy" "r938"  but appears the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `@Grab` groovy annotation at the beginning of your script.

like this your script runs fine.

result is strange - but that's another question)

```
@Grab(group='org.xhtmlrenderer', module='core-renderer', version='R8')
@Grab(group='net.sf.jtidy', module='jtidy', version='r938')

import java.awt.Dimension
import java.awt.Graphics2D
import java.awt.RenderingHints
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import org.w3c.dom.Document
import org.w3c.tidy.Tidy
import org.xhtmlrenderer.simple.Graphics2DRenderer

def makeThumbnail(address) {
  // Size for the renderer
    def WIDTH = 1280
    def HEIGHT = 800

    // Setup Tidy
    def tidy = new Tidy()
    tidy.with {
        setQuiet(true)
        setXHTML(true)
        setHideComments(true)
        setInputEncoding("UTF-8")
        setOutputEncoding("UTF-8")
        setShowErrors(0)
        setShowWarnings(false)
    }

    def url = new URL(address)
    def doc = tidy.parseDOM(new ByteArrayInputStream(url.text.getBytes("UTF-8")), null)
    def os = new FileOutputStream("${System.env.USERPROFILE}/${url.getHost()}.png")

    def buf = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)

    def graphics = buf.createGraphics()
    def renderer = new Graphics2DRenderer()

    renderer.with {
        setDocument(doc, address)
        layout(graphics, new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        render(graphics)
        graphics.dispose()
        ImageIO.write(buf, "png", os)
    }
}

makeThumbnail("http://en.wikipedia.org/")
```